# MUI Autocomplete prevent blur from closing when opening option menu

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have an autocomplete menu that I want to add a dropdown menu for each item. However, whenever I open the autocomplete, it will close as soon as I click the button to open the menu.

Below is an image of what the autocomplete looks like before opening the menu.
[autocomplete menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pqm4c.png)

Below is the code showing the issue

```
import "./styles.css";
import TextField from "@mui/material/TextField";
import Autocomplete from "@mui/material/Autocomplete";
import * as React from "react";
import Button from "@mui/material/Button";
import Menu from "@mui/material/Menu";
import MenuItem from "@mui/material/MenuItem";

const options = [
  { key: "1", value: "Option One" },
  { key: "2", value: "Option Two" }
];

function BasicMenu({ option }) {
  const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = React.useState(null);
  const open = Boolean(anchorEl);
  const handleClick = (event) => {
    event.stopPropagation();
    setAnchorEl(event.currentTarget);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Button
        color="success"
        variant="contained"
        id={`basic-button-${option.key}`}
        aria-controls={open ? `basic-menu-${option.key}` : undefined}
        aria-haspopup="true"
        aria-expanded={open ? "true" : undefined}
        onClick={handleClick}
      >
        open {option.value} menu
      </Button>
      <Menu
        id={`basic-menu-${option.key}`}
        anchorEl={anchorEl}
        open={open}
        MenuListProps={{
          "aria-labelledby": `basic-button-${option.key}`
        }}
      >
        <MenuItem>Do with {option.value}</MenuItem>
      </Menu>
    </div>
  );
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Autocomplete
        onClose={(e, reason) => {
          console.log(reason);
        }}
        getOptionLabel={({ value }) => value}
        renderOption={(props, value) => (
          <li {...props}>
            {value.value}
            <BasicMenu option={value} />
          </li>
        )}
        disablePortal
        id="combo-box-demo"
        options={options}
        renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} label="Option" />}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

I have tried adding `event.stopPropagation()` and giving the menus and buttons unique ids in case it made a difference. In the onClose function, I log the reason for it closing which is due to **blur**.

What I want to happen is when the user clicks on the green button, the autocomplete stays open. When the user clicks anywhere else within the option, it should select that option and close as normal. When the user clicks outside of the autocomplete element, it should close as normal.

Answer (score 0):

try adding this prop to the AutoComplete disableCloseOnSelect, you can find more details here : https://mui.com/material-ui/api/autocomplete

```
<Autocomplete
    onClose={(e, reason) => {
      console.log(reason);
    }}
    getOptionLabel={({ value }) => value}
    renderOption={(props, value) => (
      <li {...props}>
        {value.value}
        <BasicMenu option={value} />
      </li>
    )}
    disablePortal
    disableCloseOnSelect
    id="combo-box-demo"
    options={options}
    renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} label="Option" />}
 />
```

If that still doesn't work you can actually control the open prop manually, you can put in a useState, and set it to true, false yourself when you want the popper to close or open, this way you implement your own open/close logic

Answer (score 0):

I have these options to keep options menu open even if I focus out of it I hope it helps

```
open={true}
disableCloseOnSelect={true}
blurOnSelect={false}
onBlurCapture={(e)=>{
    e.preventDefault()
    e.stopPropagation()
}}
```